# android: eclipse not showing line number of Layout class cast exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am working on a fairly complex activity, with fragments and custom views. The activity itself has a layout file consisting of a LinearLayout with other children views. Recently, I added two children views inside a FrameLayout because I need them to superimpose each other as opposed to follow each other in a vertical sequence. As a result I started getting the following error. I understand and anticipated the possible error, but the problem is that the trace is not anchoring the error in my project. I don't know where in my code to pin down the error. Say my activity name is DogActivity, normally there should be some line `com.company.app.DogActivity.java (45)` for instance. But not in this case. I am include the trace below. Does anyone know how I might configure eclipse to show the line in my actual code that causes the exception?

```
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:683)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1418)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:709)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2425)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1876)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1010)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-27 22:37:59.181: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using different Parameter for views.it wont say exact line no where the exception occurred. check all your views where you misplaced the Layout.Parameter.

> **For example suppose you are using RelativeLayout but some where u set parameter as LinearLayout params. or if u use Table layout and
>   parameter as RelativeLayou.PayoutParams.**